What happens in GitHub if artifact names conflicts?
I have a matrix in a GitHub action. What happens if the the matrix uses upload-artifacts and specifies an artifact-name with a literal, such that other jobs in the matrix have the same artifact name?

You'll get this error,

Error: Failed to CreateArtifact: Received non-retryable error: Failed request: (409) Conflict: an artifact with this name already exists on the workflow run

Your only options are to set overwrite: true in @actions/upload-artifact or to get the fatal error above.
